# AutoCloseable and garbage collection relation

Tags: java, garbage-collection

So I've read all about the autocloseable interface and try with resources, but that makes me wonder:

What happens if I do not(forgot) to wrap a class which implements AutoCloseable with a try with resources in a code which uses that class, but that class does take resources from the OS?
While there is no guarantee on when JVM will decide it is time to call its garbage collector, when it does, will it call the close() method?

If not,is this where I will miss C++'s destructor? :) 
Is there a similar way to make sure, from within that class's code and not the user's code, that once the object should be released (for example out of scope) it will release all the OS resources it has taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add any such documentation. Just make it `Closeable` or `Autocloseable` and everybody will know. At most, add a short comment "Don't forget to call `close()`" to a method/constructor used for obtaining an instance.

> If not,is this where I will miss C++'s destructor?

For sure, you'll miss them. There's no real replacement in Java. `finalize()` and friends are rather unusable. Before the GC kicks in, you may long have run out of resources (file descriptors or alike).

You may use `finalize()` or alike for printing a warning. If the object gets GC'ed without having been closed before, it's a resource leak.

There are static analysis tools which flag non-closed resources. No idea, if they work with custom objects, but I'd bet that they look at all classes implementing (auto-)closeable.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the class. Some do implement the `finalize()` method which is called when the GC collects the object, and do call `close();`, but it's not guaranteed.

Note that although you might think "yeehaw, Java does have destructors!" it's not the same thing, and you're not advised to start implementing `finalize()` in your own classes (I can't remember writing one in all my 16 years of Java programming).

You've already made the mistake when you've forgotten to close your resources, so fix that instead. With `AutoCloseable` it's a lot more convenient than it used to be too.

Comment: Thanks for responding but the main confusion points on my part remain intact: I want NOT to depend on the user code. A user is any code which uses the class. So that if someone somewhere does forget to explicitly call close() or otherwise use try-with-resources, no disaster will happen. When you wrote some use close() some use finalize(), did you mean some implementation of garbage collectors? Again: as the designer of a class which uses OS resources,I want to do my best so that even forgetful users will be alright :) I hope that makes sense

Comment: It is very likely that there is nothing useful you can do here. You _can_ implement `finalize`, but that's only going to achieve something if you are interfacing directly with OS resources that have broken APIs. If you are using an API from a `java.` package, then it will almost certainly have a proper `finalize` implementation as a method of last resort. There's nothing to gain from writing your own.

Comment: OK so just to make sure: You guys are telling me that there is no sensible way to avoid adding the following documentation to that class: "When using this class,make sure to call the close() method,or use try-with-resources, and if you forget to do so, resources might potentially leak depending on your gc implementation". And on top of that, there is no way to make the compiler warn my users when misusing this class. Is this correct?

Comment: There's no need to. JDK classes like `FileInputStream` already implement `finalize()`, so resources are closed. For your own classes I'd avoid commenting such long drivel. If the user is reading the documentation, he'll see `AutoCloseable` and a `close()` method, and possibly an example on how to use the class (if there's a standard idiom). If the user isn't reading the documentation, then why should you care? You can't make it fool proof, because there are a lot of fools who attempt programming, and you can spend your time better.